# pipe dd to sha256sum

Tags: sha256, dd

I need to get the sha256 hash of a chunk of a binary file.
I wrote a little shell script for that task:

```
dd if=$1 skip=$2 count=$3 bs=1 | sha256sum
```

When I test it, I get the following result:

```
bernardo@bernardo-ThinkCentre-Edge72:~$ ./test.sh test.bin 10 20
20+0 records in
20+0 records out
20 bytes (20 B) copied, 0,000100981 s, 198 kB/s
7d9330a7c51eabe36a81a6cff308ac4d2035e63d7a356fc112f4fcd16208f43d  -
```

Does that mean the hash is based solely on the chunk output by dd, or did it also use dd's feedback "20+0 records in..."?

Answer (score 2):

This is the actual block stream hash (does not include the STDOUT text in the hash). You can verify this by dumping the contents to a separate file and checksumming that file using the of= option. You will get the same hash results.

You can also hash a few 0'd out blocks and you will find the same hash results with different count increment output enumerated 
(meaning it is outside the calculation).

I.E.
root@host:~# dd if=/dev/sda count=2 bs=1M | sha256sum #Hash first two blocks as a single chunk

2+0 records in/out
2097152 bytes (2.1 MB) copied, 0.0121433 s, 173 MB/s
**2e7e3388326c978b7b08d884ad3f737eb8ca6bce3fe57d7294ca96a768da6d81**  -

root@host:~# dd if=/dev/sda count=2 bs=1M >> /some_nonexistent_file && sha256sum /some_nonexistent_file #Write and hash output stream result.

2+0 records in/out
2097152 bytes (2.1 MB) copied, 0.00182897 s, 1.1 GB/s
**2e7e3388326c978b7b08d884ad3f737eb8ca6bce3fe57d7294ca96a768da6d81** /some_nonexistent_file